# Hibernate multiple table names for 1 model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I don't even know how to title my question so if it's sounds not right my apologize...

Let's say I have 1 model like that:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Bank{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String currency;
    private double amount;

}
```

And I would like to have multiple tables depends of currency.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can create one concrete class by currency, and use the JPA strategy "Table by class inheritence".

one abstract bankink class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Bank {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private double amount;
  ...
}
```

One concret class for EUR :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_EUR")
public class BankEUR extends Bank {

}
```

One concret class for USD :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_USD")
public class BankUSD extends Bank {

}
```

And so on.

Comment: but needs noting that he can no longer have IDENTITY strategy if he does that ...